# Stripe Payments Charge

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to control the charge date in Stripe?  For example, we need to charge:

1. One-time charge ($5) that needs to be charged on the purchase date.
2. One-time set up fee ($99) that is charged after 30 days from the purchase date.
3. Recurring charge ($79) that needs to be charged at the end of the term (It can be either Monthly or recurring)

Is that possible to have all these charges in the same subscription?  If so how to do it with Stripe APIs?

Answer (score 1):

When you set up a subscription with Stripe, you define price and interval they are charged.  There is an option to have a trial period, so that you can have the first charge delayed - but beyond that there are not other options. Note that subscription plan details (price, interval, etc.) are, by design, not editable

In order to implement the business rules you have listed, you will need to implement that yourself.  You can do so by:

- create a subscription plan with X day trial (I'm not 100% sure if that's what you mean by 'to be charged at the end of the term').
- creating the customer and saving a card for that customer.
- charge the one-time charge on the purchase date.
- start the subscription for the user on the purchase date (or 30 days later, depending on what is meant by 'end of the term').
- then charge the 'set up fee' charge 30 days later.

There may be some services (such as Azure's Logic App Service) that could help you implement this business process but you won't be able to do it with just Stripe.

Comment: If I am not mistaking, you need a cron job that makes the actual charge, is that correct? Or does Stripe do the periodic payments?

Comment: @JohnAndrews - it does not require a cron job on your part. The charge (or failure) will in fact trigger an event which you can handle with a webhook.